# How to produce letters to separate groups in makeindex

Tags: makeindex

I read that the lethead_flag specifier with a positive integer attribute will cause makeindex to insert lethead_prefix and lethead_suffix with a capital letter between them at the start of a new letter group in the index. I created a *.isty file as shown:

```
lethead_flag
1
```

When I run makeindex -s main.isty main.idx I see the following terminal output:

> % makeindex -s main.isty main.idx
> This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2021] (kpathsea + Thai support). Scanning style file
> ./main.istydone (0 attributes redefined, 1 ignored). Scanning input
> file main.idx....done (737 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Sorting
> entries.........done (7732 comparisons). Generating output file
> main.ind....done (727 lines written, 0 warnings). Output written in
> main.ind. Transcript written in main.ilg.

The *.isty file is being read, but the specifier and it attribute are ignored. Does anyone have a working example of an *.isty file? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: instead of specifier `lethead_flag` use specifier `headings_flag`, instead of `lethead_prefix` use `heading_prefix`, and instead of `lethead_suffix` use `heading_suffix`.